# Flutter: How correctly maintain session for file Download / or extract Embed PDF via JavaScript?

Tags: flutter, download, flutter-inappwebview

I am stuck a little with a file Download.
I am navigating with an Headless-InAppWebView to a certain page which contains a pdf file embedded in an iframe.

```
<iframe src="../xyz.pdf" />
```

I need to download this PDF file to the device. Right now I always used

```
CookieManager().getCookies()
```

and Flutter Downloader or a simple http.get with the Cookies inside the Header.

```
http.get(fileurl, headers: {"Cookie":cookies});
```

However this does not seem do to the Job for all pages.

On another Server this results in error not authorized. How do I correctly maintain the session from WebView to Download a file from there, or is there another way to extract the bytes from the embedded file? Or maybe extract the file from WebView Cache?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Some troubleshooting showed the following:
Cookies via CookieManager().getCookies and javaScript "document.cookie" are missing half the cookies that are beeing needed.
I used Fiddler Everywhere, to check the requests, and it has many more Cookies in the Request. 
So how can I make sure I have ALL cookies that I need for the current session?

Comment: To further clarify. webview cookie manager fails as the Cookie is having a Format that webview cookie manager doesnt like. It throws an exception.

Example Cookie:
ISAWPLB{21B8A963-08B8-4182-BB62-95CD0CEEE9DC}={68CF861A-E382-45D6-BC7C-9FFB87B95834};